# How to load images in batches in tensorflow?

Tags: python, image, tensorflow

I have been using pytorch and is new to tensorflow.
In pytorch we create loader class to which return single tuple of dataset and then pass the instance of the class to torch.data.Dataloader and define the batch-size and worker.
How do we do the same process in tensorflow?

```
class Dataset_Tuple_Loader(data.Dataset):


def __init__(self,img_root, csv_label_address, transforms,img_source ='local'):
    add = img_root
    if(img_source=='network'):
        add,csv_label_address,status = DataDownload(img_root,csv_label_address)
    self.imgs_address_list = glob.glob(add + '/*')
    labels_csv = pd.read_csv(csv_label_address)
    labels_csv.set_index('image_name', inplace=True)
    self.labels_csv = labels_csv
    self.transforms = transforms


def __len__(self):
    return len(self.imgs_address_list)

def get_filename(self,filename):
    base = os.path.basename(filename)
    return (os.path.splitext(base)[0])

def __getitem__(self,index):
    img_add = self.imgs_address_list[index]
    img = Image.open(img_add)
    img = self.transforms(np.asarray(img))
    filename = self.get_filename(img_add)
    label = int(self.labels_csv.loc[filename][0])
    return img,label


params = {'batch_size': 2,
      'shuffle': True,
      'num_workers': 1}

csv = 'label_address'
image_root = 'img_add'
just_set = Dataset('local',image_root,csv)


generator = data.DataLoader(just_set,**params)


for tup in generator:
    img = tup[0]
    lb = tup[1]
    print(img.shape,' ',lb)
```

Comment: When you make your dataset object one of its methods is batch() which you can call and will make your dataset produce batches.

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets

Comment: This is a complete example of a data loading pipeline with preprocessing and batching: https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/load_data/images